Express Session not persisting through redirect in production with RedisStore
I am building a web app that uses session storage for key user identifying variables. In development, I used the default express-session MemoryStore with no issues. After deploying my node.js backend to render, I changed my storage method from MemoryStore to RedisStore. In development, session storage still works with no issues, but when trying to service my frontend with the render-deployed backend, the session does not persist through redirects.
I have verified that the session is being initialized and stored in Redis through the Redis Cloud console. Additionally, I can see in the render logs that the session is in fact being set prior to the redirect. Here is some of my code below.
"server.js" Session Storage Set-up:
const redis = require('redis');
const connectRedis = require('connect-redis');
const app = express();

app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:5173", credentials: true}))

console.log("starting redis..")

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  password: '******',
  legacyMode: true,
  socket: {
      host: '******',
      port: 15653
  }
});

app.use(cookie_parser());

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
  secret: 'sparo-secret-1213nksdhk20hidfOKL',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  proxy: true,
  cookie: {
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false,
      maxAge: 3600000,
      sameSite: "none",
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000) 
  }
}))

redisClient.connect()

redisClient.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected to Redis');
});

redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Redis error:', err);
});

Render Console Logs
Session prior to redirect:
Session {
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM  cookie: {
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM    path: '/',
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM    _expires: 2024-07-24T14:42:51.367Z,
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM    originalMaxAge: 3560246,
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM    httpOnly: false,
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM    secure: false,
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM    sameSite: 'none'
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM  },
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM  sub: '******',
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM  name: '******',
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM  email: '******',
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM  refresh_token: '******',
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM  access_token: '******'
Jul 24 09:43:31 AM}

Session after redirect:
Session {
Jul 24 09:43:32 AM  cookie: {
Jul 24 09:43:32 AM    path: '/',
Jul 24 09:43:32 AM    _expires: 2024-07-24T14:42:51.367Z,
Jul 24 09:43:32 AM    originalMaxAge: 3558480,
Jul 24 09:43:32 AM    httpOnly: false,
Jul 24 09:43:32 AM    secure: false,
Jul 24 09:43:32 AM    sameSite: 'none'
Jul 24 09:43:32 AM  }
Jul 24 09:43:32 AM}

I have tried every solution proposed on similar StackOverflow questions to address this session persistence issue and none have been successful. I would appreciate any suggestions!
